# Removing garbage characters like ™, ¼, Ä from a string in vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

How can I remove all the special characters like `¼`, `¢`, `®`, `»` in a string?  By *special* or *garbage* characters, I mean ones that aren't easily type-able on a normal keyboard.  Can this be done with regex?

Comment: What are garbage characters? What are non-garbage characters?

Comment: define garbage characters. Otherwise, define the set of characters which are not considered garbage, then remove anything from the string that is not found inside the set.

Comment: I don't what should I call characters like that. I think it isn't special or what. By garbage characters I mean the characters usually can be seen on the Character Map if you're on Windows and isn't shown on a normal keyboard

Comment: @lamandy characters usually not seen on a normal keyboard. I've added some examples on my post. I think you guys cannot view it?

Comment: Usually the proper fix is to *know* the encoding of the data you receive, and handle it accordintly. The problem may be upstream from you, but just quietly discarding the "bad data" is just sweeping the problem under the rug.

Comment: Garbage characters are the ones you wouldn't want to have in your strings :)

Comment: Trying to assign meaning to "garbage", I conclude this must be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please [edit] to say what your higher goal is. (My keyboard doesn't show any lowercase letters—except for sc ab aps ock nsert ome age p elete nd age own trl hift rint creen ys q croll ause reak um ns ell nter.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx) to do this:

```
Dim input As String = "Hello World ® and StackOverflow ¼"
Dim result As String = (New Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 \!\.\[\]\(\)]")).Replace(input, "")

'result: "Hello World  and StackOverflow "
```

In this example all characters except a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and some characters are removed (whitelist).

---

You can also use the following to work with a character map:

```
Dim input As String = "Hello World ® and StackOverflow ¼"
Dim strClean As String = ""

For Each charItem As Char In input
    If Asc(charItem) > 127 Then
        Continue For
    Else
        strClean &= charItem
    End If
Next

'strClean: "Hello World  and StackOverflow "
```

In this example all characters from the extended ASCII codes are removed ([ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)).

---

As @StevenDoggart already mentioned in the comments you can also use [categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories) and [named-blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#SupportedNamedBlocks) to solve this:

```
Dim input As String = "Hello World, ® and StackOverflow ¼ ¢ »!.? ({[]})"
Dim result As String = (New Regex("[^\p{L}\p{Po}\p{Ps}\p{Pe}\p{Z}]")).Replace(input, "")

'result: "Hello World,  and StackOverflow   !.? ({[]})"
```

or the following solution:

```
Dim input As String = "Hello World, ® and StackOverflow ¼ ¢ »!.? ({[]})"
Dim result As String = (New Regex("[^\p{IsBasicLatin}]")).Replace(input, "")

'result: "Hello World,  and StackOverflow   !.? ({[]})"
```

Comment: This would probably be better, safer, and more sensitive to i18n issues if you used a combination of [unicode categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#unicode-category-or-unicode-block-p) rather than custom listing every character.

Comment: .NET supports a large set of [categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories) and [named-blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#SupportedNamedBlocks) which could be applicable, depending on the OPs needs.

Comment: For instance `Regex.Replace(input, "\P{IsBasicLatin}")` would remove all the characters he mentioned (though that doesn't make it work well in other cultures).